# How did people ‘copy paste’ cmds in old days?

Tags: linux, bash

I find myself using `history | grep  ‘whatever'` then copying and pasting the cmd, and I find this tedious.

I also sometimes do `$(history | grep 'whatever')` to execute the cmd if it’s 1 line (more than that and I have to process it) but I have to use `sed` to strip the line numbers.

So when copy paste wasn’t available did people just retype cmds? Or did they just use `sed` and `awk` to process then execute?

Comment: That depends on the person. One way is to use `CTRL + R` and begin typing the command to bring it up and then `ENTER` to run it. That is still done today.

Comment: Hmm damn… I wish I knew that before… thanks

Comment: @nasirriley what about if you tested a cmd on terminal and then want to copy that to a file?

Comment: `history | grep 'whatever' > x` followed by a `vi x`

Comment: Original `/bin/sh` didn't have command history at all, so you typically _didn't_ work on the command line in this way; you'd build a quick temporary script and execute that (especially if you were iterating through commands to get your `grep`/`awk`/`sed` command right.  `vi x`...blahblah...`sh x`.  `csh` provided a command history, but used a totally different syntax to `sh`.  It did, however let you recall previous commands (eg with `!!` and change them prior to exection).  With `ksh` and `bash` you can even bring the previous command into an editor with the `fc` command.

Comment: They were using "history substitution", and that's why the csh shell (which introduced it) was such a hit. For instance, instead of Ctrl-R, Up or `history | grep` and copy pasting, they were just typing `!?whatever`. Or `!?whatever?:s/t/tso/` to search the command containing `whatever`, and replace it with `whatsoever` before executing it, `^foo^bar` for the previous command while replacing `foo` with `bar`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking from my own history here, not necessarily UNIX chronological order.

In the "old days" there was neither command line editing nor mouse. You literally retyped the command, as you would for vanilla `sh` or `dash`. I suspect this was one reason why commonly used commands were short. Simple scripts in a personal `$HOME/bin` directory incorporated in the `$PATH` helped with more frequently used operations.

For a number of years this was my environment, augmented by X Windows running on a PC ([XVision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visionware)), which allowed me to copy and paste with a mouse.

Then came the C Shell (`csh`) with its command history. Still no command line editing but you could repeat previous commands and perform simple modifications to them. Here, `%` is the C Shell prompt:

```
% echo hello, world
hello, world

% ^world^earth
echo hello, earth
hello, earth

% history
    12  echo hello, world
    13  echo hello, earth
    14  history

% !13
echo hello, earth
hello, earth

% !13:s/hello/goodbye
echo goodbye, earth
goodbye, earth

% !h
history
    12  echo hello, world
    13  echo hello, earth
    14  history
    15  echo hello, earth
    16  echo goodbye, earth
    17  history
```

Then came `tcsh` which offered a command line editing tool. This became my favourite session shell for a number of years, although what scripts I wrote were for `sh`.

Then I discovered `bash`, which meant I could use `history` and command line substitution (with `^old^new`, as above) but also the the same syntax as for my scripts. I've not yet moved to `zsh` so this is my current preferred environment.

Comment: ksh had command line recall and interactive editing from as far back as 1983. csh with history expansion was from the late 70s. bash really was a serious downgrade from an interactive use PoV compared to tcsh up to 2.0 in 1996 (by which time zsh was already immensely superior to both).

Comment: I don't think I ever really used ksh; no reason other than I didn't know about it. My route started around 1984/85 with sh → csh → tcsh → bash. There was a mix of BSD, Ultrix, SysV.2/3/4, and BSDI but I didn't want to add that to the answer because it didn't seem relelvant. I suspect my introduction to bash was around the very late 90s or even early 00s when I found Linux.

Comment: I really liked the `csh` syntax/substitution that @UncleBilly commented above and you're still using and shown that it's possible for `bash` thanks a lot

Comment: @Nickotine sometimes I use that even in `bash` - it can be faster than editing a line with cursor keys

Comment: Instead of viewing the history list just to get the number, one would have changed the prompt to display the command number, or (with a good memory) one could select the command by string instead of number, like `!vi:1`. See also http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/cshhistory.html and "History substitutions" in https://lxu.io/linux-man-pages/csh.htm.

Answer (score 2):

Bash offers some options to avoid retyping commands on a terminal, where copy & paste is not available.

The most useful one is probably **CTRL+R**, which allows you to do a reverse search in your history.

**ALT+.** inserts the argument from the last command.

**CTRL+I** or **TAB** autocompletes commands, filenames, and directory names.  **ALT+/** autocompletes filenames and directory names only.

**CTRL+ALT+E** expands the Bash alias currently entered on the command line.

And then, of course, you have the **UP** and **DOWN** arrow keys to navigate throughout the history and select an already run command.

Comment: Bash definitely isn't from the "old days".

Comment: @U.Windl 1989 might not be "old days" but actually `bash` is software with a surprisingly long pedigree